# Función Booleana recursiva me devuelve siempre False

Tags: c++, recursión

```
bool Arbol::enArbolR(nodoArbol * nodoActual,string _titulo){
    if (nodoActual != NULL){
       if (iguales(_titulo,nodoActual->book.GetTitulo()))
            return true;
       enArbolR(nodoActual -> izq,_titulo);
       enArbolR(nodoActual -> der,_titulo);
    }else return false;
}
```

La función iguales la testee en un programa aparte y funciona, también probé poniéndole return a las llamadas recursivas de enArbolR y aun así me devuelve siempre false.

Se que en el árbol tengo que comparar si (titulo<árbol.titulo) y luego llamo a la función recursiva, pero el **árbol no esta ordenado por titulo** solamente tengo que recorrer todos los nodos del árbol fijándome si se encuentra el titulo.

Note que si al if(iguales()) lo pongo al principio de los llamados recursivos siempre retorna False y si lo pongo al final de los llamados retorna siempre True

Comment: Por lo general en las funciones recursivas debe ir tu caso base al principio, en este caso la comparación de los títulos, ya que si esta como en el ejemplo nunca llega a compararse y llegan hasta el final de los items retornando siempre false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función recursiva está mal planteada. Se puede observar lo que quieres hacer, pero no lo estás haciendo bien.

Para empezar, se te ha olvidado tratar un caso, que es la causa de tu fallo, de que siempre devuelva `false`.

Copiando tu código y haciendo algún cambio menor:

```
bool Arbol::enArbolR(nodoArbol * nodoActual, string titulo)
{
    if (nodoActual != NULL)
    {
        enArbolR(nodoActual->izq, titulo);
        enArbolR(nodoActual->der, titulo);
        if (iguales(titulo, nodoActual->book.GetTitulo())) return true;
        //else (caso sin tratar)
    }
    else return false;
    // En el caso sin tratar el flujo de ejecución llega aquí
}
```

Si te fijas, hay un caso `else` que no tratas. Si el nodo no es nulo, y el nombre del libro al que apunta no es igual al parámetro `titulo`. Si ocurre este caso, no se ejecuta ni el `return true` ni el `return false`.

En tu caso, el compilador que estas usando ha decidido ayudarte y devolver un `false` para el caso sin tratar (a veces los compiladores pueden devolver valores implícitos cuando no hay un `return` en un método que devuelve valores).

Si lo compilas en otra máquina, con otro compilador, o con otra configuración, probablemente el programa ejecutable no se genere por un error de programación en la línea donde falta un `return`.

Sin embargo, agregar una sentencia `return true` o `return false` no solucionaría tu problema, porque el caso sin tratar se debe a que no has tratado bien la recursión.

Los valores devueltos por las llamadas recursivas a `enArbolR` devuelven valores que no guardas ni utilizas para nada, por lo que incluso si alguna ha encontrado el libro indicado, el nivel padre desecha la información que el hijo le da de que lo ha encontrado.

La solución es guardar los resultados en variables y utilizar estas en condiciones, o bien utilizarlos en una condición del padre, sin utilizar variables intermedias.

```
bool Arbol::enArbolR(nodoArbol * nodoActual, string titulo)
{
    if (nodoActual != NULL)
    {
        if (iguales(titulo, nodoActual->book.GetTitulo())) return true;
        else return enArbolR(nodoActual->izq, titulo) || enArbolR(nodoActual->der, titulo);
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Y simplificando un poco el código:

```
bool Arbol::enArbolR(nodoArbol * nodoActual, string titulo)
{
    if (nodo == null) return false;
    if (iguales(titulo, nodoActual->book.GetTitulo())) return true;
    return enArbolR(nodoActual->izq, titulo) || enArbolR(nodoActual->der, titulo);
}
```

Comment: Cabe destacar que con la edición que has hecho de tu propio código sigue habiendo un caso sin tratar y sigue ocurriendo el mismo error.